# How to use findByIdAndUpdate on mongodb2.4?

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

backbone client update a model property:

```
ocase.save({ currentStep : theStep },callback);
```

server side mongoose code :

```
OCase.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
        req.body, callback);
```

it works fine on mongodb2.6, but it doesn't work on mongodb2.4, and the error is :

```
update err:MongoError: exception: Mod on _id not allowed
```

so I tried to remove "_id",and only save other attributes:

```
OCase.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
            {subject    : req.body.subject,
            description : req.body.description    
        },callback);
```

then I got another error :

```
update err:TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

I am really confused, what can I do now?

Finally, I have to query(findById) the document first, and then call "save" method to update.

```
OCase.findById(req.params.id,
        function(err,ocase){
            ocase.set(req.body);
            ocase.save(function(err,ocase){
                res.send(ocase);

            });
        });
```

Comment: Works may be a bit of a broad statement here. Unless the "update" document in the statement is using the [$set ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator then you are overwriting the whole document, which is probably not the most ideal thing to do. The general wire protocol between versions has not changed. Best edit your question to include more information on the request being passed in and the schema for the model you are updating.

Comment: Thanks! it works with "$set" operator. I still have the question about the different behavior between the two mongodb versions. There must be something changed on mongodb2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solve it by adding the `$set` operator:

```
OCase.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: {
            subject: req.body.subject,
            description: req.body.description,
            currentStep: req.body.currentStep
        }
    }, callback);
```